# What is the Doctrine query to get range of records without using Ids?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, entity

I am using the following function to get the range of records (using Doctrine repository).
I want all records starting from 50th record to 100th record. Here 50 is not the Id of the record it is the 50th record in the count; in the same way 100 is not the id it is 100th record in the count.

But this function do not meet my above requirement as it must know the id of the first record.

So my question is - what should be my query in this case?

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;
 
class OrdersRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getOrders($entityManager,$from,$to)
    {
        $query = $entityManager->createQuery("SELECT o FROM Application\Entity\Orders o WHERE o.ordersId BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2");
        $query->setParameter(1, $from);
        $query->setParameter(2, $to);

        return $query->getResult(); 

    }

}
```

Comment: `ORDER BY o.ordersId LIMIT 50, 50`

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```
class OrdersRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getOrders($entityManager,$from,$to)
    {
       
        $query = $entityManager->createQuery("SELECT o FROM Application\Entity\Orders o ");
        $query->setFirstResult($from)
            ->setMaxResults($to-$from);

        return $query->getResult();

    }

}
```

Please advise if there is a better solution.